# Spring Security custom ldapAuthenticationProvider + custom ldapAuthoritiesPopulator

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Is it possible to have a custom ldap authentication provider along with custom ldap authorities populator?

I don't want to restart my application each time ldap server is unreachable for a short moment (So i need the custom provider, to create a new context and override authenticate method on each login).

On the other side, i need to create custom roles for each membership of ldap user (need to override the getGrantedAuthorities)

Answer (score 0):

For implementing custom ldap authentication provider you need to create class that extends from `AbstractLdapAuthenticator`

```java
public class BindPasswordAuthentificator extends AbstractLdapAuthenticator {

    public BindPasswordAuthentificator(BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        super(contextSource);
    }

    @Override
    public DirContextOperations authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        DirContextOperations user;

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String)authentication.getCredentials();

        user = authenticateByLdap(username, password); // authenticate user here

        if (user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                    messages.getMessage("BindAuthenticator.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

And for implementing ldap authorities populator you need to create class that extends from `LdapAuthoritiesPopulator`

```java
public class CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {
 
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> gauth = new HashSet<>();
        //you need to place logic for populating user authorities here
        return gauth;
    }
}
```

After that you need to configure these two classes in your configuration

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${life.ldap.server}")
    private String ldapServer;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authentificator(), authPopulator());
    }

    @Bean
    public BindPasswordAuthentificator authentificator() {
        return new BindPasswordAuthentificator(contextSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
        return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapServer);
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authPopulator() {
        CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator result = new CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please provide some explaination to it. How does one implement `authenticateByLdap(username, password);`.
How to setup `ldap url`, `userdn` & `groupSearchBase("ou=groups")`

thanks