# LDAP Custom AuthnticationProvider Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security-ldap

I have to validate browser credentials against my LDAP. But Username/Password given in Browser has to be used to connect to LDAP, its not fixed userDN and password.After authentication, I get the roles from LDAP only. I saw various examples of suggesting AuthenticationProvider.authenticate. But I want to know what method I need to use to authenticate or search user, which will return me user object with roles. Please guide . This helps me [Spring Security custom ldapAuthenticationProvider + custom ldapAuthoritiesPopulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533063/spring-security-custom-ldapauthenticationprovider-custom-ldapauthoritiespopula), but i need to know how to implement authenticateByLdap mentioned here so that it returns DirContextOperations

Comment: Have you tried using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider method ?

Comment: Can you please provide me a sample

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider  ( Check example 2) which you can configure using Spring Security